# a connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'sql browser' service is running

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssid

So Im trying this sql server 2012, and I cant open any ssis package due to this error

a connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'sql browser' service is running

my Sql Browser is running for sure, I tried changing it under local service, local system and network, still no result yet, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917670.aspx)? Written for 2005 but basics should still apply.

Answer (score 7):

This error seems to related only to named instances.  The reason is SQL client is not able to resolve instance because SQL client has no access SQL Browser Service.  SQL Browser Service resolves instance name

1. Ensure SQL browser service is running
2. Ensure the port on which SQL browser service runs, is not blocked from PC (default port 2382)

Alternatively, you can bypass SQL Browser Service, by mentioning "Server:Port" instead of "Server\instance name", in the client connection properties