# SQL Server 2012 "SQL Browser" Service

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssdt-bi

As a preface, I have done some checking around on this issue but found nothing that solves my question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005007/a-connection-cannot-be-made-to-redirector-ensure-that-sql-browser-service-is) question was the closest I found but the answer did not resolve my issue.

Information about configuration: My local machine is Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 and SSDT-BI installed. On the server machine I have SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition installed on  Windows Server 2012 Standard. The data is coming from a third party database installed on a CentOS5 server.

I am trying to deploy a cube to my Analysis Services server, but I am getting the following error: "A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running."

I have checked and the SQL Browser service is running both on my local machine and the server machine. As well, rather than connecting via < Server Name >\< Instance Name > I have tried connecting with IPAddress:Port.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but in case it is: the database I am using to define the cube I'm trying to deploy is on a different server and has different authentication than my SQL Server 2012 Instance. Moving the data to the SQL Server is not an option.

Comment: So you are sure this is not a firewall issue? Can you deploy locally on the server if you copy your project files over there?

Comment: No it was an authentication/networking issue. Not what I expected from the error message.

Comment: I received this error. Turns out I misspelled the name of the deployment server in Project Properties Deployment page.

Answer (score 0):

To FrankPl: just to chime in, you answered my question a few hours ago which is essentially the same problem: VS2012 Pro with SSDT-BI installed, also Update-3 and the Aug.2013 update to AS. We're unable to connect and/or open a project.